# React passing new props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

So I update my state in a component and then pass the new props into the child but the child isn't updating correctly and the defaultValue of the input is not changing. At first I thought it might be because I am using this.props so begun using this.states and applying the new props there first but doesn't seem to be working.

Parent Component

```
this.state.newDetails == null ? '' : 
    <NewDetailsView details={this.state.newDetails} />
```

Child component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class NewDetailsView extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      details: (this.props.details!= null) ? this.props.details: null
    }
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({ details: nextProps });
    this.forceUpdate();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" defaultValue={this.state.details.id} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default NewDetailsView ;
```

**Solution Code:**

Pending...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React input defaultValue doesn't update with state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30146105/react-input-defaultvalue-doesnt-update-with-state)

Comment: Slightly different, figured it out before bed will post solution tonight when I get home :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Issue is inside the `componentWillReceiveProps`:

```
this.setState({ details: nextProps });
```

it should be :

```
this.setState({ details: nextProps.details });
```

And also remove `this.forceUpdate();` , there is no need of `forceUpdate` here.

---

Sultion to second issue change `defaultValue` to just `value` :

```
<input type="text" value={this.state.details.id} />
```

---

Here is the link to working example :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-parent-child-prop

Comment: This worked except the input value is still not updating, the state changes though

Comment: found something similar here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43976513/componentwillreceiveprops-in-child-doesnt-receive-new-props-when-setstate-in?rq=1

Comment: hmm yeh last issue is the defaultValue field not changing despite state changing though

Comment: If a value is available inside a component as prop, there is no need to transfer it to state and then use that state. It adds unnecessary complexity to your code and is a wasteful practice.

Answer (score 0):

```
const NewDetailsView = ({details}) => (
  <div>
    <input type="text" value={details? details.id: null} />
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `getDerivedStateFromProps` instead of using deprecated `componentWillReceiveProps`. An example of it can be found [here](https://hackernoon.com/replacing-componentwillreceiveprops-with-getderivedstatefromprops-c3956f7ce607)

Answer (score 0):

maybe as me you got into this question, In React v16.3.0 some methods became legacy (deprecated), in this example do not use this `componentWillReceiveProps`, now is known as `UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps` and can lend you through errors and bugs.

Instead look a the example below:

```js
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    if (nextProps.someValue !== prevState.someValue) {
      return {
        someState: nextProps.someValue,
      };
    } else return null;
  }
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevProps.someValue !== this.props.someValue ) {
      this.setState({
        someState: this.props.someValue ,
      });
    }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

That is the correct way of Update a component.

Ref: [Replacing ‘componentWillReceiveProps’ with ‘getDerivedStateFromProps’](https://hackernoon.com/replacing-componentwillreceiveprops-with-getderivedstatefromprops-c3956f7ce607)

Answer (score -1):

`defaultValue` only works for the initial load. You should controller input and use props to get value (don't need setState).

[React Passing](https://jsfiddle.net/tutv95/snzt7vx6/)